# Creating a tab using react native elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-elements

I have to create a tab bar with react-native-elements.
Can any body help to create it with this.
The code given in the below link is kind of incomplete.
It will be nice if you could make it working in a react component.
Thanks in advance.

https://reactnativeelements.com/docs/tab

Comment: Why do you say it's incomplete?

Comment: Everything you need to create a tabbar is literally in that link that you post. What is not clear enough for you in the docs? what are you missing to create your tabbar?

Comment: @HimanshuGupta I am having confusion in setting the setIndex. You can copy the code in the sandbox and let me know how it will work.

Comment: @MarijnBerends I am having confusion in setting the index. if you just copy the code in the code-sandbox you will come to know. If you can show me a working example in code-sandbox it would be really helpful in understanding it

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working version of this: https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-golick-upnok?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Big thanks to you brother for helping me out but when I implement the same code I get error ===>

undefined is not an object (evaluating '_$$_REQUIRE(_dependencyMap[6], "react-native-elements").TabView.Item')

Comment: The sandbox i shared is supposed to work with react environment and not react native env. I somehow made it work with react native by importing dependencies. You asked about setting the index. Don't copy my code. Just look at how I am setting the index and please accept the answer if that works. That should help others also.

Answer (score 0):

i create tab from react native element so here is the link. and go to the bottom of the page and there will be all the code availbale with expo

https://reactnativeelements.com/docs/components/tab

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32514992)